# Cannot start Chromium

Tags: chromium, ubuntu-15.10, odroid

I am trying to start Chromium 49.0.2623.108 on Ubuntu 15.10 installed on my ODROID-XU4. It used to work all the time but from one day to the next Chromium will not start. When I try to run it via terminal I get:

```
~$ chromium-browser
[3813:3840:0101/015306:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(925)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for www.google.com failed err=-8181
[3813:3840:0101/015306:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(925)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for translate.googleapis.com failed err=-8181
[3813:3839:0101/015306:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(925)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for clients2.google.com failed err=-8181
Segmentation fault
odroid@odroid:~$ libGL error: unable to load driver: exynos_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: exynos
[3866:3866:0101/015307:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(334)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
```

Any idea what I can do?

I have already tried reinstalling Chromium. That did not solve the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bumped for interest. I have the exact same problem on the exact same environment (software & hardware). By the way -- this question is probably more well-suited for SuperUser, rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like rolling Chromium back to version `45.0.2454.101` works as a temporary solution (although it'd still be great if someone got the newest version to work). To do this, I had to go through the following steps:

1. Run `sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser` to remove the broken version of the package
2. Get the list of available package versions via `sudo apt-cache showpkg chromium-browser` (at the time of writing, there were two: `50.0.2661.102` (newest) and `45.0.2454.101`)
3. Install the older version, like so: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser=45.0.2454.101-0ubuntu1.1201`
4. (Optional) If you got a dependency error during the previous step, execute these two first: `sudo apt-get remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` and `sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra=45.0.2454.101-0ubuntu1.1201`
5. Chromium should start up fine now

This worked for two of my Odroid XU4's running `Ubuntu 15.10` and Chromium `50.0.2661.102` (before the downgrade).

EDIT: looks like this problem affects all ARM-based single board computers, rather than the Odroid XU4 in particular (although the reference to `exynos_dri.so` might make it look like an Odroid XU4 issue). See [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/bug-report-chromium-crashes-on-start/4511) for more information + other ways to rollback to an older version.

EDIT #2: There also seems to be [a way](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/tutorial-install-working-chromium-50/6762) to get the newest version to work, but I have not tried this out so I don't know whether it will actually work or not.